# How to upload custom jars to Maven repository

Tags: maven, repository, uploading

I have a custom jar named core-ui-1.0.jar which is based on Spring. I used http://download.java.net/maven/2/ repository to download spring jars to compile my java files inside core-ui-1.0.jar. Now my core-ui-1.0.jar is ready to release

Can someone help me how can I release my core-ui jar to http ://download.java.net/maven/2/ so that any person can download it from maven 2 repository the way we download spring, hibernate jars etc.

Please let me know if I have the right to upload anything to http://download.java.net/maven/2/ or am I thinking in wrong direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably won't be able to use that repository. Instead use a Corporate Maven repository (such as Artifactory or Nexus) to upload your own JARs and make it available to others inside your company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a release. I suggest using the maven-release-plugin if you're build is based on maven.

To have your artifacts available in maven central follow the instructions here:

- http://maven.apache.org/repository/index.html (and follow the links)
- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

  - I think this applies best to your project: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html
- http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html
- http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will proceed with the given steps. If I find any difficulty, I will revert back.